# Transmitting differential video signal to the ADC input

Tags: analog, adc, differential, video, differential-amplifier

I'm designing a circuit that converts a single-ended analog video signal (f = 10 MHz) to a differential pair and then is processing the data to a digital form. The signal is transmitted through a shielded 1-meter-long cable to the remote PCB with ADC of differential input (LTC2227). Is there any contraindication to feeding the signal directly from cable to these inputs or should it be processed through the buffer amplifier first? I'm planning to use THS4505DR and the line converting circuit is roughly depicted in the schematics by Texas Instruments ([THS4505DR datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ths4505.pdf)):
[image: Single-ended to differential pair]

Comment: It would be most logical to put the THS4505DR next to the ADC so that you didn't have to run a third cable for the Vcm line, but given the low bandwidth I don't see a problem with running through a short cable.

Comment: Actually they spec a pretty wide range of voltage for Vcm, so you could probably generate it locally if needed.

Comment: @user1850479 I am actually planning to generate 1,500 V for the Vcm input using the separate voltage reference source. By converting the video to a differential signal before it runs through the cable I hope to make it more immune to disturbance. Please correct me if there's any misconception.

Comment: I think there is no point in converting to differential to send a 10 MHz signal 1 m. Any half decent coax cable can do that.